# Segment Routing to factory instead of controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am currently setting up a ZF2 application and got stuck with the router. I looked up Zend's example for segmented routing:

```
$route = Segment::factory(array(
    'route' => '/:controller[/:action]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ),
));
```

By calling http://example.com/Maps/edit Zend would automatically "navigate" to the MapController and call EditAction().
Since I use Factory for the MapController I am looking for a solution like

```
$route = Segment::factory(array(
    'route' => '/:factory[/:action]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'factory' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'factory' => 'Application\Controller\Factory\DefaultControllerFactory',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ),
));
```

Basically I want the framework to access the factory instead of the controller without listing any single factory manually.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

controller manager is ServiceManager, all service manager features applies. Register controller factory instead of declaring it as invokable